How keep alive and foreground an app with React Native
My next app will run on a kiosk in a museum.
So I'm looking for a way to limit access to other apps (and settings).
And then, always keep alive and foreground my app.
After listed the installed apps width react-native-check-app-install and react-native-launcher-kit,
I tried react-native-app-locker with an error : cannot read property lockApp
After research, I add to the manifest :
android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES
android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE
queries
intent>

  

The app still crashes.
So I tried an other way : use AppState to detect when my app is background and restart with react-native-restart or react-native-launcher-kit but it's not working in produce.
Any idea ?
my config :
targetSdk: 34
java: 20
React Native: 0.73.6
gradle: 8.3
tests on an Android 11 tab
